# read_csv function in tidyverse not understanding `col_select`

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to read a subset of a large data set using read_csv with defined columns of interest using the `col_select` and lazy = T options. However, my read_csv does not seem understand those options and throws an error at me:

```
"Error in read_csv("d_labitems.csv.gz", col_names = T, col_select = c(itemid,  : 
  unused arguments (col_select = c(itemid, label), lazy = T)"
```

Any tips on why this could be happening are appreciated!

just to clarify: read_csv should have those options (readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html ), and I used those just a day ago while working on a server. The problem occurs only when I work on my local machine.

Comment: `readr::read_csv` just does not have arguments `lazy` or `col_select`. Seems that you use a reader from a database in which stuff is often lazy...

Comment: lazy reading is by default, from the help page I am not sure if the ```TRUE``` argument is valid, try without it

Comment: The words *"unused arguments"* are a clear error in R: those arguments are not recognized for that function. When you see that (for `read_csv` or any other function), you should read through `?read_csv` (or whichever function) and see what argument names are actually present. Perhaps you have a typo, confusing arguments between different functions, or ... just making things up.

Comment: Thank you all for the thoughts! so according to the tidyverse web site, read_csv should have those options (readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html ), and I used them just a day ago while working on a server. The problem occurs only when I work on my local machine.

Comment: Is the version of `readr` on your local machine the same as that on the server?  If not, update.